# C# - SqlComand - Select con inner join entre 2 BD

Tags: c#, sql

Tengo la siguiente situación:

Estoy desarrollando con C# una app de escritorio que básicamente muestra en una grilla datos de una consulta (query select).

Mi problema esta en que este `select` tiene un `inner join` que lo hace entre 2 tablas de dos bases de datos distintas y cuando lo ejecuto solo me trae datos de una parte y no completa el query porque necesita conexión con la otra base.

¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Ejemplo:

```
SqlCommand consultarTEMP = new SqlCommand("SELECT [NroFactura],serie.SL ,serie.ArtW as ArticuloWMS, 
serie.PartDec as DescripcionParte ,serie.Storenumber as Sucursal, Estado
FROM[BD1].[dbo].[Temp_Serie] f 
LEFT JOIN[BD2].[dbo].[Temp_Ejmplo2] serie ON f.NroFactura = serie.SL 
Where Serie.SL Is not Null order by Estado", conn);
```

Comment: No es algo que debes solucionar desde el programa. Ese query debe funcionar desde tu base de datos, necesitas que haya una conexion entre las dos bases de datos.

Comment: Podes probar linkeando un servidor en tu base de datos, asi cuando hagas la consulta todas las conexiones externas estaran en base de datos, te dejo un ejemplo de como linkear un servidor https://www.sqlshack.com/es/como-crear-y-configurar-un-servidor-enlazado-en-sql-server-management-studio/

Comment: Solo sera posible si las credenciales que utilizaste tiene acceso a ambas base de datos. Si tiene acceso, entonces ejecuta tu sql en un IDE y verifica tu sql  que algo esta mal.

Comment: ¿Las dos bases están en un mismo servidor? ¿Qué motor estás usando? ¿cual es realmente el problema? ¿la "query" funciona pero no retorna los datos que esperas o directamente no funciona y de da un error? si es el último caso ¿Qué error te da? ¿El problema es con un `inner join` o un `left join`?

Comment: Por las dudas, ¿has notado que tienes un error tipográfico aquí: `JOIN[BD2]..[dbo].[Temp_Ejmplo2`? hay un punto de mas.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho si lo del error tipográfico lo puse así para el ejemplo anda mas. si las bases están en el mismo servidor no sabría decirte, lo que si te confirmo es que esa misma query la ejecuto en el Sql Management funciona sin problemas conextandome a solo una de las dos bases. Para conectarme al servidor uso un String de conexión que si solo se conecta a una de las dos bases, creo que seria aquí mi problema que no se como hacer para que se conecte a las dos bases, estoy invetigando de usar un SP como lo dijo Kevin Restrepo

Comment: Eso se resolvería con un linked server, de forma que el motor pueda resolver la consulta completa y entregar un único resultSet. Hacerlo como lo estás pensando te daría dos conjuntos separados de datos que deberían filtrar y procesar tú mismo... y creo que sería reinventar la rueda

Comment: Podes usar un SP, pero el problema no es por ahi. El problema es que el usuario que estas usando desde el sistema no tiene permisos para ver la otra base de datos desde la base de datos a la cual te conectas. Si te conectaras con el mismo usuario que usas para el Sql MG andaria igual. Pero seguro usas otro y a ese le tenes que dar permisos de vista sobre la otra base de datos.

Comment: tienes dos intancias de sql instaladas? y una base de datos en cada instancia o las dos bases de datos estan en la misma instancia? porque si es lo ultimo solo agrega el mismo usuario de sql a la otra base de datos desde la pestaña Security y Users

Comment: el linked server esta hecho entre las dos bases pero me da el siguiente error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'No se encuentra el servidor 'AXPROD - SQLCLU' en sys.servers. Compruebe que se haya especificado el nombre de servidor correcto. Si es necesario, ejecute el procedimiento almacenado sp_addlinkedserver para agregar el servidor a sys.servers.'